# Is there a keyboard shortcut to turn a tab-delimited recordset into a table?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

I have a text file containing records of data that's tab-delimited.  I like to paste it into an email, select it, and go to `Insert > Table > Insert Table` to turn the tabbed data into a legit table.

If there were a single shortcut key combination that would do this, that would be great.

Comment: are any of the letters underlined in the menu selections? if so, you can use ALT+UnderlinedLetter to select those specific items